# thrift: command not found

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, thrift

I got

```
 % mvn install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------< com.xx:yy-java-client >------------------
[INFO] Building yy-java-client 3.3.9-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1:enforce (default-enforce) @ yy-java-client ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- sortpom-maven-plugin:2.8.0:verify (default-verify) @ yy-java-client ---
[INFO] Verifying file /Users/cp/gocode/src/code.xx.internal/data/yy-java-client/pom.xml
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-thrift-plugin:0.1.11:compile (default-compile) @ yy-java-client ---
[ERROR] thrift failed output: 
[ERROR] thrift failed error: /bin/sh: thrift: command not found

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.777 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-12-12T23:33:28-05:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.thrift.tools:maven-thrift-plugin:0.1.11:compile (default-compile) on project yy-java-client: thrift did not exit cleanly. Review output for more information. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Any idea why? thanks

Comment: Is the `thrift` command is in you path?

Comment: got any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install thrift, this error means it's not installed
check this page on how to install it, https://thrift.apache.org/